# Virtual Host is not working in Zend Framework after multiple tries at fixing things

Tags: zend-framework, virtual, host

In both the sites-available and sites-enabled folders, I have a conf file called "zend-framework.conf".  This is what I have contained in the file.

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
     # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
     # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
     # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
     # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
     # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
     # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
     # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
     ServerName zendlocalhost
     ServerAlias zendlocalhost
     ServerAdmin root@localhost
     DocumentRoot /var/www/zend-framework/public
     SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
     <Directory /var/www/zend-framework/public>
         DirectoryIndex index.php
         AllowOverride All
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from All
     </Directory>

     # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
     # error, crit, alert, emerg.
     # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
     # modules, e.g.
     #LogLevel info ssl:warn

     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

     # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
     # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
     # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
     # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
     # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
     #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf 
</VirtualHost>
```

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet

This is what I have in my etc/hosts file

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
#127.0.1.1  lazerorca-iMac
127.0.0.1   zendlocalhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

This is what I have in my ports.conf file.  I get a message saying that NameVirtualHost *:80 is going to be deprecated in a later version.  I tried adding that only because I saw it in another question

```
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
 Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
 Listen 443
</IfModule>

NameVirtualHost *:80

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

This is the error I get when I go to `http://zendlocalhost`

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at root@localhost to inform
>   them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed
>   just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.

This is what access.log says

> 127.0.0.1 - - [16/Dec/2014:15:05:22 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 798 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101
>   Firefox/35.0"

This is what the error.log says

> [Tue Dec 16 15:25:20.271792 2014] [core:alert] [pid 4825] [client
>   127.0.0.1:60826] /var/www/zend-framework/public/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not
>   included in the server configuration

I check the .htaccess file and it looks ok to me, but evidently it isn't.  here is what is in the .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The 
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to 
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size 
# fits all solution.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

Interestingly enough if I go to `http://zendlocalhost/phpmyadmin` it pulls up
If I go to 127.0.0.1, it pulls up the generic Ubuntu apache index.html file
I am very new to Zend as in this is my first time trying it out.  i know there are some crazy URL rewriting and such.  I would have thought going to the root address would have pulled up the index.php file.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

Apache doesn't understand `RewriteEngine`, the very first directive in your .htaccess. This means mod_rewrite is not enabled. If you're on Ubuntu, run `sudo a2enmod rewrite`, and then restart Apache and try again.